# BLDC controller

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, switching, winding

I have to design a controller for three phase BLDC motor. In BLDC motor, for each hall sensor signal combination we have to to energize two sets of stator phases. But how to correctly identify which phase has to be energized for a particular combination? In application notes by Microchip or TI, there are lookup tables showing sequence of energizing coils, but how did they identify that sequence? Is it through experiment or are we randomly selecting two phases?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://learnengineering.org/brushless-dc-motor.html) explains the idea and principle of operation of BLDC motors, which should help you make a decision on what logic to use.

> The operation of a BLDC is based on the simple force interaction between the permanent magnet and the electromagnet. In this condition, when the coil A is energized, the opposite poles of the rotor and stator are attracted to each other [...]. As a result the rotor poles move near to the energized stator.
>
> As the rotor nears coil A, coil B is energized. As the rotor nears coil B, coil C is energized.

Comment: video only answers are not recommended here. Abstract the useful info from the video into your answer.